# Xamarin bar code scanner ZXing.Net Mobile

Tags: xamarin.android

I am working on an Xamarin.Forms application. Specifically, I am focusing on the Android platform before I focus on iOS. So far in my application I have implemented login and registration. When I was working on the login and registration features of the application all the work that I did was in the PCL, which would compile into android and iOS.

However, I now want to implement barcode scanning. For this requirement I have decided to use the ZXing.Net.Mobile for Forms library. After reading the documentation it says the following var scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();. I have download ZXing.Net.Mobile for Forms in my Xamarin.Android solution however it is unable to find the class. Any help or guidance would be great thanks.

Comment: I solved the problem by installing ZXing.Net.Mobile forms

Comment: If this could help you, can you please mark it as answer ?

Answer (score 0):

> I have download ZXing.Net.Mobile for Forms in my Xamarin.Android solution however it is unable to find the class

If you just install the `ZXing.Net.Mobile` nuget package, it's unable to find the class.

[image]

You could see the [ZXing.Net.Mobile](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/master/Source/ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms/ZXingScannerPage.cs) source code, the `ZXingScannerPage.cs` class is included in `ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms`. So you need download the `ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms` nuget package :

[image]

Then you could get started with [ZXingScannerPage](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/zxing.net.mobile.forms) :

```
var scanPage = new ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ZXingScannerPage();
```